# MIPS Pseudoinstructions Dealing With li (big, small)

Tags: mips

As a disclaimer, this is a for a school assignment, but I've been trying to understand this specific section of my homework for a few hours and I'm not finding any solution.  I've googled, attempted to look up videos, read my book, etc.

I have a general gist of the normal MIPS instructions (still very much a beginner), but I'm very confused with some of the pseudoinstructions.  We are asked to convert 10 or 12 pseudoinstructions to MIPS instructions.

I understand the simple pseudoinstructions, such as:

```
move &t1, $t2 # add $t1, $t2, $zero
```

But I'm very confused at ones involving "big," and "small," and "li"

`li $t1, small` (the hint we're given is "$t1 = small" which makes no sense to me, what is "small" in this context?).

Where I'm confused is, usually an immediate relates to a hard coded value, like 1 or 5, but I see no hard coded value.  What am I supposed to be storing in $t1?  I read that small means to 16 bit numbers and big is 32 bit, but what number are they referencing in this pseudoinstruction?  There is only one register here and no hard value, what am I loading into $t1?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'd guess `small` == any number that fits in 16 bits, and `large` == any number that fits in 32 bits but requires more than 16 bits. Ask your teacher to verify if uncertain.

Comment: Michael is [probably] correct. For 16 bits (e.g.) `li $t1,97` --> `addi $t1,$zero,97`. For 32 bits, (e.g.) `li $t1,0x12345678` --> `lui $t1,0x1234` `ori $t1,$t1,0x5678`. For the 32 bit case, note that you _can't_ always do this with an "equate" (e.g. in spim: `big = 0x12345678` in mars: `.eqv big 0x12345678`) because there is _no_ syntax for: `lui $t1,UP(big)` `ori $t1,$t1,LO(big)` where [in C macros]: `#define UP(x) x>>16` and `#define LO(x) x&0xffff`. Only the _assembler_ can do the UP/LO _internally_. Likewise for `la` Some assemblers _will_ provide UP/LO but mars/spim don't

Comment: I'm still entirely confused.  How can I write a solution where I'm storing a 16 bit value into $t1 if I dont have a 16 bit value specified anywhere in the question?  I'm very lost and have been reading more today.  I'm a beginner in MIPS so I'm probably misunderstanding the question.  To make matters worse, I'm trying to run code in SPIM to figure out what these are actually doing and every. single. bit of code I try (samples from the net) throws errors in SPIM on Mac.  Very frustrating.

Comment: @Michael you were correct, the small and large labels were just "variables" representing any number of that category.  I was confused because that section said we had to be "real" mips code and I know MIPS code can't didn't have any instructions for those labels, so I had no clue what they were asking, but yes, you were correct.  If you want to make an "answer," I'll accept it for reputation.